# EC2 and SSL certificate error: None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a running ec2 instance associated with an elastic IP which points to my domain. however, after getting ssl_handshake eror, I checked the Elastic IP from sslshoper.com to see if my ssl was correctly installed but I got the warning below:

[image]

Please what does it mean and how can I solve the problem? I've checked every configuration and everything seems to be fine. I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: It means you tried connecting using a url like `https://1.2.35.211/whatever` but your certificate doesn't contain `1.2.35.211` as one of the subject alternative names (SANs). Your certificate only contains SANS like `example.com` and `www.example.com`, so every URL must specify the hostname as either `example.com` or `www.example.com` and not `1.2.35.211`.